# Calculate execution time of a SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am providing search functionality in my website, when user searches a record then I want to display the time the query taken to get the results same as google does. When we search anything then google displays how much time it takes to get results?

For this I have declared a @start variable in my SP and finding the difference in the end, as below;

```
DECLARE @start_time DATETIME

SET @start_time = GETDATE()

-- my query
SELECT * FROM @search_temp_table

SELECT RTRIM(CAST(DATEDIFF(MS, @start_time, GETDATE()) AS CHAR(10))) AS 'TimeTaken'
```

Is there any other easy and fast way, or a single line of query with which we can find out the time a query taken to execute?

I'm using SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

We monitor this from the application code, just to include the time required to establish/close the connection and transmit data across the network.  It's pretty straight-forward...

```
Dim Duration as TimeSpan
Dim StartTime as DateTime = DateTime.Now

'Call the database here and execute your SQL statement

Duration = DateTime.Now.Subtract(StartTime)
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Query took {0} seconds", Duration.TotalSeconds.ToString()))
Console.ReadLine()
```

Comment: one must use `System.Diagnostics.StopWatch` for this ideally.

Comment: I downvoted your anwser, because it doesn't answer the actual question. Fine that you have solved it by using VB, but consider marking the answer of faiz as the right answer

Answer (score 90):

Well, If you really want to do it in your DB there is a more accurate way as given in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190287.aspx):

```
SET STATISTICS TIME ON
```

You can read this information from your application as well.

Comment: How can this information be read by the application?  Microsoft's article doesn't mention anything about it.  I left them feedback asking if I have to parse the message output, or if there is a more structured way to access the timing data, specifically with .NET framework classes.

Comment: Good but a little detailed how it breaks the time down for every event, I just need total time between 2 points

Comment: @Triynko: The timings can be read in the [`SqlConnection.InfoMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.infomessage(v=vs.110).aspx)-event

Comment: more information about the above can be found here: http://www.sqlserver.info/management-studio/show-query-execution-time/

Answer (score 26):

I found this one more helpful and simple

```
DECLARE @StartTime datetime,@EndTime datetime   
SELECT @StartTime=GETDATE() 
--Your Query to be run goes here--  
SELECT @EndTime=GETDATE()   
SELECT DATEDIFF(ms,@StartTime,@EndTime) AS [Duration in milliseconds]
```

Comment: It's in milliseconds not microseconds
DECLARE @StartTime datetime = GETDATE(),@EndTime datetime   

SET @EndTime=GETDATE()   
SELECT DATEDIFF(ms,@StartTime,@EndTime) AS [Duration in milliseconds]

Comment: this won't work as these are runtime constants and are assigned values at when query first runs, not as it is executed

Comment: @mark1234 I didnt get what u told. Which one don't work?

Comment: see here http://sqlblog.com/blogs/andrew_kelly/archive/2008/03/01/when-a-function-is-indeed-a-constant.aspx

Comment: @mark1234 Ok.Gud article. But when i use above query i didnt get same time for StartTime and EndTime. It was different. What do u mean by values are assigned when query first runs?

Comment: I've tried it on a bunch of occasions and while start and end may not be exactly same time, they were nowhere near accurate. For example, in a recent project, my entire SP (which included an index rebuild that takes 6 minutes) reported less than 1 minute. I got better results using datediff(millisecond, @Startdate, getdate()). I presume this is because this function isn't evaluated until it's reached during execution. I don;t have the exact answer, but just assigning Getdate to Start and End variables was way off for me

Answer (score 17):

Please use

```
-- turn on statistics IO for IO related 
SET STATISTICS IO ON 
GO
```

and for time calculation use

```
SET STATISTICS TIME ON
GO
```

then It will give result for every query . In messages window near query input window.

Answer (score 14):

```
declare @sttime  datetime
set @sttime=getdate()
print @sttime
Select * from ProductMaster   
SELECT RTRIM(CAST(DATEDIFF(MS, @sttime, GETDATE()) AS CHAR(10))) AS 'TimeTaken'
```

Answer (score 10):

Why are you doing it in SQL? Admittedly that does show a "true" query time as opposed to the query time + time taken to shuffle data each way across the network, but it's polluting your database code. I doubt that your users will care - in fact, they'd probably *rather* include the network time, as it all contributes to the time taken for them to see the page.

Why not do the timing in your web application code? Aside from anything else, that means that for cases where you *don't* want to do any timing, but you want to execute the same proc, you don't need to mess around with something you don't need.

Comment: Although the total time of connection + query + network transfer is very practical, I'd prefer to exclude the network transfer time since so many factors external to the search engine can affect it.  I also like the idea of having queries that return performance metadata, so the application can monitor itself.  That would allow an application to automatically exclude or replace queries when the load is high or warn the developer if a query that produces a sum, for example, starts to regularly exceed some threshold as the target table sizes grow.

Comment: Also, when you're adding incremental functionality, the additional overhead of the query may be negligible, while the query time itself may not be.  For example, I want to send back one additional integer to my Flash client with a new sum query, so the overhead can be considered negligible (i.e. *existing* data stream increases by only 4 or 5 bytes and database connection is already being opened for the other retrieved data), while the query execution time may be significant.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
SET STATISTICS TIME { ON | OFF }
```

Displays the number of milliseconds required to parse, compile, and execute each statement

When SET STATISTICS TIME is ON, the time statistics for a statement are displayed. When OFF, the time statistics are not displayed

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;  
GO         
SET STATISTICS TIME ON;  
GO  
SELECT ProductID, StartDate, EndDate, StandardCost   
FROM Production.ProductCostHistory  
WHERE StandardCost < 500.00;  
GO  
SET STATISTICS TIME OFF;  
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
DECLARE @StartTime DATETIME
SET @StartTime = GETDATE()

  SET @EndTime = GETDATE()
  PRINT 'StartTime = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),@StartTime,121)
  PRINT '  EndTime = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),@EndTime,121)
  PRINT ' Duration = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),@EndTime -@starttime,114)
```

If that doesn't do it, then try SET STATISTICS TIME ON