# How to get correct query execution time in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I need to get the execution time of my query. I am using

```
declare @starttime datetime
declare @endtime datetime
set @starttime =getdate()   

 -- execute my query here

set @endtime = GETDATE()
select @endtime-@starttime
```

But the output is coming as `1900-01-01 00:02:10.707`

I need only the time part.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/595762/calculate-execution-time-of-a-sql-query

Answer (score 67):

Use this:

```
set statistics time on
--query
set statistics time off
```

then go to the 'Message' tab to see a message like this:

```
 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 165 ms.
```

Answer (score 13):

Set the STATISTICS TIME option:

```
SET STATISTICS TIME { ON | OFF }
```

Example:

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO 

SET STATISTICS TIME ON;    
GO

SELECT ProductID, StartDate, EndDate, StandardCost 
FROM Production.ProductCostHistory
WHERE StandardCost < 500.00;    
GO

SET STATISTICS TIME OFF;    
GO
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx) datatype which is available in SQL Server 2008 and higher

Now the tags are correct and this is SQL Server 2005...

```
select CONVERT(varchar(12), @endtime-@starttime, 114)
```

Comment: @user2360877: so why tag this SQL Server 2008?

Answer (score 3):

Try with this different convertion after your diff:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),@endtime-@starttime, 108)  -- 00:02:10
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),@endtime-@starttime, 114)  -- 00:02:10.707
```

108 and 114 represent the format type for date conversion, please refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 3):

```
DECLARE @StartTime datetime,@EndTime datetime   
SELECT @StartTime=GETDATE()
```

--Your Query to be run goes here--

```
SELECT @EndTime=GETDATE()   
SELECT DATEDIFF(ms,@StartTime,@EndTime) AS [Duration in milliseconds]
```

Comment: the duration is in milliseconds, not microseconds. Change ms to mcs for microseconds

Answer (score 3):

An update for those who are using later versions of SQL Server than the OP: In SQL server 2017 (version 14.0), the time taken by the query and the number of rows affected is shown by default under Messages tab.
[image: A screen clip after I ran a query, I'm using Azure Data Studio]

Answer (score 3):

You should have used `DATEDIFF(MICROSECOND, @starttime, @endtime)` to get the elapsed time in milliseconds, so your query should be changed to something like this:

```
DECLARE @starttime datetime
DECLARE @endtime datetime

SET @starttime =getdate()   

-- execute my query here

SET @endtime = GETDATE()

SELECT DATEDIFF(MICROSECOND, @starttime, @endtime)
```

Although you can use a built-in feature named `Include Client Statistics` which has been explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57801490/4344976).

Answer (score 0):

In SSMS, In the Menu bar:
Go to

1.Query>Query options>Advanced>SET STATISTICS TIME

2.Query>Query options>Advanced>SET STATISTICS IO

That will give the output looking something like this in your Messages window:

SQL Server parse and compile time:
CPU time = x ms, elapsed time = y ms.

SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = x ms, elapsed time = y ms.