# Using * in SELECT queries

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I read somewhere that never use * to return all columns in a table–it’s lazy. In this case, if I need all 5 columns and there won't be any changes to the table later, are there any performances difference in:

```
SELECT * 
from table
```

vs.

```
SELECT id,col1,col2,col3,col4 
from table
```

Comment: This might help [Why is SELECT * considered harmful?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639861/why-is-select-considered-harmful)

Comment: There really isn't a performance difference. It's mainly a caveat because in team environments, you'll never know when someone may add 20 columns (one of which is a 2M blob). That would definitely cause a performance issue.

Comment: If you use “*” the database engine have to look for the field for you.

Comment: If performance is your concern, you should try and time those queries. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/595762/calculate-execution-time-of-a-sql-query) out

Comment: @a52: and? It will have to do that for `select col1, col2 ...` just as well.

Comment: This statement is not true: "*there won't be any changes to the table later*" - experience shows that there **will** be a change at some point.

Comment: If it is an ad hoc query you are not going to save in any way shape or form * can be fine. If not type out the solumn names. There are tons and tons of articles on this. If you type in `select *` bad into google you will probably get a million results.

Comment: @a52 please stop spreading this terrible myth. SQL Server still has to validate that col1, col2 exist, validate their data types, etc. in either case.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a noticeable performance difference, but in production code I would stick with an explicit column list:

- It's clearer
- There's no way you can *absolutely* know there will never be a column that is added, removed, or changed
- It's easier to update the query later to do something like alias a column
- If you end up having to add a `JOIN` to that query, things could get interesting if you keep the `SELECT *`

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any difference. It's just bad practice - if you modify `table` later on it may break some more complex queries (like queries across multiple tables) if they use `*`.

Comment: There is a difference in some platforms.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO for example?

Comment: [Bullet point 4](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3180435/679449) and [this article](http://bi-bigdata.com/2012/09/02/select-vs-select-in-sql-server-query/)

Comment: @wroniasty - I once saw a SQL Server view that was along the lines of `SELECT A.*, B.X, C.Y, D.Z`, and when table A had a column added to the end of it, the view kept the captions intact, returned the same number of columns as before, but the last column of A was returned where B.X was, B.X got moved to C.Y's column, and D.Z simply didn't get returned.  I immediately updated the view to call out the specific columns, and no more problems.

Comment: Read @AaronBertrands comment in the main question you are wrong.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables your example is scary, but - I stand corrected

Comment: @Zane doing `SELECT *` and `SELECT [all columns in table]` is the same thing - the same number of lookups in the meta data